# Trouble Sending WhatsApp Template Messages via Twilio - Error 63016

Tags: twilio

I'm facing an issue with sending WhatsApp template messages using Twilio, and I'm hoping to get some guidance on how to resolve it. Specifically, I'm encountering error code 63016, and I'm not sure how to fix it.

## Problem Description

I'm attempting to send WhatsApp template messages through Twilio, and I have a valid WhatsApp Business account set up with approved templates. The code I'm using seems to work fine for simple messages, but when I try to use placeholders within the template, I receive error code 63016, indicating that something is amiss with the templates.

## My template

`Hello {{1}} this is a template for testing twilio whatsapp messages service.`

## My code

```
const accountSid = process.env.ACCOUNTSID;
const authToken =  process.env.AUTHTOKEN;
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.messages
.create({
    from: 'whatsapp:MY_NUMBER',
    body: 'Hello Joe this is a template for testing twilio whatsapp messages service.',
    to: 'whatsapp:DESTINATION_NUMBER'
})
.then(message => console.log(message.sid));
```

## What I've Checked:

- The template is valid and approved by WhatsApp Business.
- My code for sending messages works fine with simple text messages it means no placeholder syntax "{{ }}".
- I've validated the syntax and structure of the template.

Answer (score 2):

Using WhatsApp templates is quite strict and trivial-appearing whitespaces or encodings can turn a valid usage of a template invalid.

So I suggest double-checking these [common problems](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/tutorial/message-template-approvals-statuses#common-rejection-reasons) or using the [Content Template Builder](https://www.twilio.com/docs/content/twilio-text). In there, you can submit another template to Meta and from then on, reference the template by ID and provide the variables to plug in. I usually prefer this approach because it's more robust against the issues mentioned above.

```js
// Download the helper library from https://www.twilio.com/docs/node/install
// Find your Account SID and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
// and set the environment variables. See http://twil.io/secure
const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.messages
      .create({
         contentSid: 'HXXXXXXXXX',
         from: 'MGXXXXXXXX',
         contentVariables: JSON.stringify({
           1: 'Name'
         }),
         to: 'whatsapp:+18551234567'
       })
      .then(message => console.log(message.sid));
```

[Docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/content/send-templates-created-with-the-content-template-builder)

[WhatsApp Legacy Templates versus Content Templates](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/13847332022299-At-a-Glance-WhatsApp-Legacy-Templates-versus-Content-Templates)

Comment: RestException [Error]: A text message body or media urls must be specified.
I get this error when i am using 'contentVariables' with 'contentSid' instead of 'body'

Comment: Are you sure you are specifying a messaging service in the `from` or `messagingServiceSid` properties? This is a [requirement](https://www.twilio.com/docs/content/create-and-send-your-first-content-api-template).